# There's slats of concrete about 3 feet apart underneath wooden deck. How should we fill it inexpensively?

Tags: yard, concrete

[image]Just removed a large wooden deck in our back yard.  There are slats of concrete about 3 feet apart underneath. How should we fill it in? Sod, gravel, etc.?  Going to sell the house soon so we want an inexpensive solution but want to make it a place for an outdoor table, chairs, etc. for potential buyers.

Comment: Could these slabs be covering something? Like an old septic tank? A picture would help...

Comment: I just added a picture of the area.